# java: class Profile is public, should be declared in a file named Profile.java error for unstructured data model and pojo

Tags: java, class, methods, data-modeling, pojo

I have the following data model:
where jobs is an embedded document and the remaining

and i wrote the pojo for the above data model as below:

Comment: Did you put all the classes in separate files?

Comment: no only jobs is in a separate file, the remaining are not embedded documents so i put them in the same file i.e data.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all classes are in the same file you have to remove `public` from other classes.

If your filename is Profile.java, then, you have to use:

```
public class Profile{...}
```

The other classes like `public class Environment` you should remove the `public`:

```
class Environment{...}
class Payload{...}
class data{...}
```

I recommend use those classes in separate files, with its respective name. If you do this, you have to use the `public class` now.

Comment: if i remove public from profile, environment and payload, will they still be considered as fields in the same parent document ? and iif i remove public i wont be able to access them to insert data in the main class

Comment: @Srs yes, you can work with them without problems. About the `data` class, you will have to use as `public` and name your file as **data.java.**

Comment: Or you can also use all classes without `public` and name your file as the class will have the main. You can do that only if some class will have the `main` method and you won't have to use those classes in other files/external classes

Comment: i removed public for profile, environment and payload but it throws error when i try to use those classes in the main.java file as they are no longer public and i need to use those classes in the main method which is in a different file and class i.e main.java

Comment: Ok, that's the problem I just typed seconds ago.
If you want do that, the best way to fix it, it's using separate files for each class and also, you will have to name all those classes with `public class ...`

Comment: if i use separate files for each class how do i include it in the data.java file so that they will be considered as fields in the parent document?

Comment: If you have your classes in the same package (or folder) you don't have to do anything, only use the class name.
For example, inside **data.java** if you want to call the `Profile` class, just type:
`Profile profile = new Profile();` 
Here, you are creating a new instance from `Profile` class.

Comment: But now, if  you have your classes in other packages, you will have to use `import`:
For example, your package name is: `examples` and inside it, you have those classes **Profile.java data.java ....**
And your file **main.java** is in another package like: **MainPackage**
Then, like you have your files in separate packages, to be able to use the classes **Profile.java data.java ...** inside the file **main.java** you will have to use an `import`

Comment: To use the import, you have to type something like this:
`import examples.Profile`
With that, you will be able to use the Profile class
If have doubt about imports, packages I recommend read about them, to can understand how they work